# JaxB performance on big documents

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, xml-serialization

I'm getting response from RESTful web service which can return String up to 300kb long.

When I'm trying to unmarshal iy using JaxB2, it takes up to 12 seconds

Is there something I can do?

```
public class Convertor{

   JAXBContext responseJaxbContext;

   public Convertor(){
      requestJaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClassResponse.class);   
   }


    public MyClassResponse convertXml(String str) {
         MyClassResponse response = null;   
        try {
             Unmarshaller jaxbUnMarshaller = bookingResponseJaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
             StringReader reader = new StringReader(str);
             response = (MyClassResponse) jaxbUnMarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Update:** I disabled schema validation by using

`jaxbUnMarshaller.setSchema(null);`

Now my unmarshaling time is 5 -7 sec.

Comment: How did you measure that time? 12s for only 300kb seems a lot...

Comment: @Puce, I'm using StopWatch Spring library.

Comment: What does the XML and Object model look like?  Are there any properties of type `Object` that could be resulting in DOM nodes being created?  Is the document valid, sometimes time can be wasted with invalid values that cause internal exceptions.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, no there is no Object classes, but there is well designed schema, but even if I disable schema validation, I'm getting 5 -7 seconds unmarshaling time.

Comment: Were you setting an `Schema` before it wasn't in your question ( are you profiling different code)?  If not calling `setSchema(null)` shouldn't have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you instantiate the JAXBContext/ your Convertor class only once.

In my experiene, creating a JAXBContext is expensive.

Edit:
But that's not an explanation for 12s, I guess...

Comment: Yes, I verified that. it's created only once.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison try parsing your XML document with a SAX parser to figure our how much of the time is just spent parsing the XML document.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml; // Your XML

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = sp.getXMLReader();

        xmlReader.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler());

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);

        // Profile This
        xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
    }

}
```